# Receiving notification when not mentioned with @

Tags: support, comments, notifications

##### See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71370217/14862885)

There **in comments**

[image]

@Rasta Bearr did not mentioned me (with @),

---

But I am getting a notification:

[image]

Is there something like the *last commenter*/*all commenters* will be notified?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see all the ways in which we receive notifications to the inbox in the MSE FAQ [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/571958). Specifically to your scenario, the third bullet under the "comment" bullet under the **Posts** heading reads:

> A post’s author comments on a post you have previously commented on, when the only other (undeleted) comments on the post belong to you or the author.

In other words, if you are the ***only*** commenter (not counting the OP), then you'll get notifications even without being mentioned (pinged with `@`).